# Get a value from database column using Linq C#

Tags: linq

```
+----+------+------+-----+
| ID | Name | Pass | Age |
+----+------+------+-----+
| 1  | Alex | .... | 12  |
+----+------+------+-----+
```

I have a table like above
How can I get `Age` by `Name` by using `LinQ lambda` and store result in variable

Like this :

```
var test= db.Users.Where(x => x.Name == ...).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work for you

```
var age = db.Users.Any(x => x.Name == someName)?db.Users.First(x => x.Name == someName).Age:0;
```

Above code ensures a default value of 0, if record is not found.

You could also throw raise a custom exception if the record was not found. For example,

```
var age = db.Users.Any(x => x.Name == someName)?db.Users.First(x => x.Name == someName).Age:throw new Exception("User not found");
```

If you want to reduce round trips, you could do

```
var age = users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "someName")?.Age??throw new Exception("User not found");
```

Comment: this will throw a null reference exception, if the row doesn't exist

Comment: You are making 2 trips to the database which is unnecesary.